# MySQL Performance - JSON vs Joins

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say, I have at the moment, the following tables:

## categories

- id
- name (for example "museum", "tower" or "theater")
- some other fields...

## countries

- id
- name
- some other fields...

## cities

- id
- name
- country_id
- some other fields...

## sights

- id
- name
- city_id
- category_id
- some other fields...

### My question / problem

Now I want to combine all these table into a single table which I call "objects". Since the different tables avove haven't the same "some other fields.."-Fields, I need a flexible way of storing this data. There are 2 options:

- Storing it as a json-string in a field called "data" in the object-table
- Or storing it in a separete table "properties" (object_id, field_name, field_value)

My Questions:

- But which version would be better/has a better performace? "Json to Object conversion in PHP and string-search" vs "multiple joins"?
- For the second version: Which datatype should the field "field_value" have? This value can be filled with anything. From a boolean value to strings.

Comment: As long as your tables are properly indexed, then (performance wise) joins would still probably be more efficient (you're offloading the searching to the database, which has been designed explicitly to handle data searching), and you only transfer the data you need between the database and PHP (so data transfer overheads are reduced, and potentially reducing PHP memory demands as well)

Comment: Semantically, the structure of your tables also has meaning.... simply having a generic "objects" table loses any semantic meaning, making it harder for anybody else to understand

Comment: If you just want an "object store", and don't want to be bothered with relations on a relational database, then don't bother using a relational database.... switch to using a nosql database like couchdb or mongo.... MySQL is a __relational__ database, it works well with relational data; if you eliminate those relations, then it isn't going to work well