# MySQL columns json vs joins

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5

I am stuck with database design of holiday package inventory project which contains a main table `packages` for storing package information.

Here is the fields

1. id PK
2. package_name varchar
3. attractions json  eg-field: ['super','funny'],
4. inclusions  json  eg-field: ['hello','cool']

One package may have  many attractions and inclusions so that's why i choose a `json` field.

So is this a slandered way or keep the attractions and inclusions in another table with foreign key relation??.

if i choose second method(ie different tables for attractions and inclusions) what about searching a package with particular attraction think that search requires a join query (Search with join is a bad practice??.).

But in the first method we can apply a json search (MySQL-version >5.7 supports json search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how complex you foresee the project becoming. You can use your existing table configuration and leverage the JSON Search feature, however as your table gets bigger this will be a bigger and bigger problem for performance.
It would be better to create 4 tables, Packages, Inclusions, Attractions and Relations.

Packages

- ID (int) PK
- Name (varchar)

Attractions

- ID (int) PK
- Name (varchar)

Inclusions

- ID (int) PK
- Name (varchar)

Relations

- ID (int) PK
- PID (int) FK - Packages
- RID (int) ID of Inclusion or Attraction
- type (varchar) indicates Inclusion or Attraction

Then you can do joins to select any combination of the types and relate any number of them to eachother.

```
SELECT * FROM Packages p join Relation r ON p.ID = r.PID AND r.type = "Attraction" Left Join Attractions a ON a.ID = r.RID WHERE p.id = 1 /*specific package id*/
```

Comment: `as your table gets bigger this will be a bigger and bigger problem for performance` could you this in detail

Comment: In your example why need a `Relations` table ??

Comment: From other questions its indicated that joins are still more efficient than json searching for maintaining relationships. [mysql-performance-json-vs-joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781427/mysql-performance-json-vs-joins)

I think json searching is intended to be used more in replacing blobs of json data making it queriable and joinable rather than being a replacement for maintaining object relationships.

The Relations table just makes storing the object relations centralized and prevents the need to parse multi value fields in packages.

Comment: Maybe I was over thinking your use case, if all you are storing is the words as meta for the packages, then json searching is probably what you're looking for. If you are storing more information about the attractions and inclusions than just the names then I would create additional tables for them.